WP-Cron missing tasks after moving to server job
We moved our wp-cron off WP and over to a c-panel server job and in order to lessen our server load (which was high at the time) used
0,15    *   *   *   *   php -q /home/folder/public_html/wp-cron.php /dev/null 2>&1

But since we have been experiencing missed jobs. The most annoying has been scheduled posts, but also it's affecting certain e-commerce stuff like AutomateWoo.
Is the only solution to use wget or is 15 minutes too long of an interval?
